# What is wrong with this call to the Controller's Action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

When I Redirect user to this Url

`http://localhost:34768/Module/Edit?versionId=f4592b62-17e4-47e1-8a08-6a927a1c895e?selectedTab=0&selectedRowId=4c1fb4a6-691f-4c03-9e67-8f8b10a95c0e`

I'll get following error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a
>   null entry for parameter 'versionId'
>   of non-nullable type 'System.Guid' for
>   method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult
>   Edit(System.Guid,
>   System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],
>   System.Nullable`1[System.Guid],
>   System.String)' in
>   'ParKone.Controllers.ModuleController'.
>   An optional parameter must be a
>   reference type, a nullable type, or be
>   declared as an optional parameter.
>   Parameter name: parameters

My controller action looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Guid versionId, int? selectedTab, Guid? expandedRowId, string url = "")
```

I don't understand why `versionId` is not coming through. If I write this Url then it works smoothly.

> http://localhost:34768/Module/Edit?versionId=f4592b62-17e4-47e1-8a08-6a927a1c895e

Any ideas?

**Update**

I have this kind of line in the Web.config

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" requestPathInvalidCharacters="" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two ?'s in your url and so the routing is picking up your parameters from the second ?.  The ? is used as a separator of your parameters and your URL and so it seems that the routing takes the parameters, in this case, from the portion of the querystring after the second ?.

Comment: Excellent! I have been manipulating the Url and made mistake on that. Thanks!

Comment: @TxS - from experience  I've found that using the proxy tool fiddler , instead of staring at strings, is invaluable for troubleshooting these issues.